# autocompletar txtfield

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Estoy realizando una aplicación donde quiero que los `txtfield` me arroje una lista de las posibles palabras que puede escribir al seleccionar una letra.

Ejemplo si el usuario coloca la letra **u** se le muestre una lista (uno, único, uva, uniforme, uña, ulcera,...).

Si el usuario escribe **un** se le  muestre (uno, único, uniforme).

O también de ser posible que se muestre una lista con las posibles cadenas de texto que el usuario pueda seleccionar, al estilo del buscador del chrome

Intente realizando una prueba pero no me funciono ademas que no se, si usando `popup` me arroje el resultado que deseo.

El `frame` de prueba solo tiene un `JTextField`. como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el código fue el siguiente:

```
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public void crearPopup(){
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add("distrito");
        popup.add("Dinamarca");
        popup.add("España");
        popup.add("caracas");
        popup.add("uno");
        popup.add("unico");
        popup.add("ulcera");
        popup.add("uniforme");
        popup.add("uña");
        popup.add("alado");
        popup.add("picudo");
        texpop.add(popup);
        texpop.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
    }

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        crearPopup();
    }
```

Nunca he trabajado con `popup`, tampoco se si existe otra forma de realizar el auto completado... Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: [Prueba esto](https://stackabuse.com/example-adding-autocomplete-to-jtextfield/) o[esto](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AutocompleteTextField.htm) Nunca me he planteado un autocompletado, pero se ve que swing lo tiene listo para implementar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo he realizado es un autocomplete en el mismo JTextField, esto lo realizo mediante una clase `Autocomplete` modificada de la original de [Scott Robinson](https://stackabuse.com/example-adding-autocomplete-to-jtextfield/):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class Autocomplete implements DocumentListener {

  private static enum Mode {
    INSERT,
    COMPLETION
  };

  private JTextField textField;
  private final List<String> keywords;
  private Mode mode = Mode.INSERT;

  public Autocomplete(JTextField textField, List<String> keywords) {
    this.textField = textField;
    this.keywords = keywords;
    Collections.sort(keywords);
  }

  @Override
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) { }

  @Override
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) { }

  @Override
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getLength() != 1)
      return;

    int pos = ev.getOffset();
    String content = null;
    try {
      content = textField.getText(0, pos + 1);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    // Find where the word starts
    int w;
    for (w = pos; w >= 0; w--) {
      if (!Character.isLetter(content.charAt(w))) {
        break;
      }
    }

    String prefix = content.substring(w + 1);
    int n = Collections.binarySearch(keywords, prefix);
    if (n < 0 && -n <= keywords.size()) {
      String match = keywords.get(-n - 1);
      if (match.startsWith(prefix)) {
        // A completion is found
        String completion = match.substring(pos - w);
        // We cannot modify Document from within notification,
        // so we submit a task that does the change later
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CompletionTask(completion, pos + 1));
      }
    } else {
      // Nothing found
      mode = Mode.INSERT;
    }
  }

  public class CommitAction extends AbstractAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5794543109646743416L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
      if (mode == Mode.COMPLETION) {
        int pos = textField.getSelectionEnd();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(textField.getText());
        sb.insert(pos, " ");
        textField.setText(sb.toString());
        textField.setCaretPosition(pos + 1);
        mode = Mode.INSERT;
      } else {
        textField.replaceSelection("\t");
      }
    }
  }

  private class CompletionTask implements Runnable {
    private String completion;
    private int position;

    CompletionTask(String completion, int position) {
      this.completion = completion;
      this.position = position;
    }

    public void run() {
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(textField.getText());
      sb.insert(position, completion);
      textField.setText(sb.toString());
      textField.setCaretPosition(position + completion.length());
      textField.moveCaretPosition(position);
      mode = Mode.COMPLETION;
    }
  }

}
```

De acuerdo a tu código lo podrías implementar de esta forma:

```
List palabras = new ArrayList<String>();
palabras.add("distrito");
palabras.add("Dinamarca");
palabras.add("España");
palabras.add("caracas");
palabras.add("uno");
palabras.add("unico");
palabras.add("ulcera");
palabras.add("uniforme");
palabras.add("uña");
palabras.add("alado");
palabras.add("picudo");

// Without this, cursor always leaves text field
texpop.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

Autocomplete autoComplete = new Autocomplete(texpop, palabras);
texpop.getDocument().addDocumentListener(autoComplete);      

// Maps the tab key to the commit action, which finishes the autocomplete
// when given a suggestion
texpop.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "commit");
texpop.getActionMap().put("commit", autoComplete.new CommitAction());
```

De esta forma al escribir un texto, buscara si esta contenido en la lista mediante una búsqueda binaria y te sugerirá la palabra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias, el codigo funciona perfecto

Comment: Excelente @Dmvp, saludos!

Comment: @Elenasys me ocurrio un problema el autocompletado me funciona pero con un detalle, lo posteare como nueva pregunta :D

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa a @Dmvp respuesta de https://github.com/djasc1993/Autocompleter-Free-Java con algunos parametros y personalizacion de colores

```
//AutoCompleterExtra.DEBUG = true;
autoComplete = new AutoCompleter(jTextField1);
autoComplete.setMethodSearch(AutoCompleterInterface.MODE_SEARCH_CHAR_CONTAINS); // default MODE_SEARCH_CHAR_CONTAINS
List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("Apple");
items.add("Orange");
items.add("Mango");
autoComplete.addItems(items);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y puedas ayudar mejor a los usuarios.