# autocompletado de textfield

Tags: netbeans, java-swing

Hace unos días realice la siguiente pregunta

[autocompletar txtfield](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275062/autocompletar-txtfield)

El codigo que me facilito Elenasys me funciona pero siempre y cuando el usuario teclee al inicio una letra, ahora bien supongamos que estoy trabajando ingresando una cantidad de articulos, ahora mis ya no seria una sola palabra si no un numero + una palabra por ejemplo esta es mi lista de palabras:

```
    List palabras = new ArrayList<String>();
    palabras.add("invitar");
    palabras.add("registrar");
    palabras.add("cancelar");
    palabras.add("aceptar");
    palabras.add("eliminar");
    palabras.add("producto errado");
    palabras.add("no encontrado");
    palabras.add("error");
    palabras.add("denegado");
    palabras.add("exitoso");
    palabras.add("15 cancelar");
    palabras.add("20 aceptar");
    palabras.add("45 eliminar");
    palabras.add("48 producto errado");
    palabras.add("120 no encontrado");
    palabras.add("80 error");
    palabras.add("85 denegado");
    palabras.add("89 exitoso");
    texpop.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    AutoComplete autoComplete = new AutoComplete(texpop, palabras);
    texpop.getDocument().addDocumentListener(autoComplete);
    texpop.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "commit");
    texpop.getActionMap().put("commit", autoComplete.new CommitAction());
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa me ocurre esto:

Cuando el usuario comienza ingresando una letra funciona perfecto como se puede ver en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema se me presenta si el usuario ingresa un numero como se ve a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ingresar un numero automaticamente  completa con la opcion 120 no encontrado indiferentemente del numero que ingrese,

quizas preguntes ¿por que con el texto lleva o no lleva un numero antes?. Pasa que hago una verificacion de lo que ingresa el usuario entonces si el usuario ingresa un texto con el numero o sin el numero ambos textos son correctos dependiendo de lo que se le este solicitando al usuario

¿Que le debo modificar al codigo para que me funcione de la manera que deseo?
Muchas gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: Hola Dmvp, ¿"10 bicicletas" es un elemento en el array?

Comment: si, lo que sucede es que el programa que estoy haciendo es extenso y tiene una parte donde el usuario ingresa una serie de mensajes, ellos van acompañados de un codigo ej(el usuario puede introducir el codigo 80 Error] como puede escribir solo Error y ambas son permitidas, o puede escribir 120 No encontrado o solo No encontrado y tambien ambas son validas) editare la pregunta con los elemento que debe llevar el array para que me entiendas un poco mejor

Comment: Al no encontrar coincidencias debe devolver **"120 *"** (o "10 *", antes) porque sería el primer elemento en una lista ordenada, me suena que hay algún problema en el parseo o en la condición que determina si se va a buscar por números o por letras. Haría falta ver la parte del código en donde se hacen esas cosas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la [clase Autocomplete](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275062/autocompletar-txtfield), agrega el caso en el cual lo que escribes es un digito:

```
...
...
// Find where the word starts
int w;
for (w = pos; w >= 0; w--) {
  if (!Character.isLetter(content.charAt(w)) && !Character.isDigit(content.charAt(w))) {
      System.out.println(w + " is not letter or digit.");
    break;
  }
}
...
...
```

Comment: gracias  Elenasys y @Sal me han ayuudado a solventarlo :D

Answer (score 2):

En `Autocomplete.insertUpdate()`

Cambia

```
if (!Character.isLetter(content.charAt(w))) {
```

Por

```
if( !(  Character.isLetter(content.charAt(w)) 
     || Character.isDigit (content.charAt(w))
     )
  ) {`
```